# Scrollbars at the bottom WHY?

Tags: css, html

I really hate to ask for help with this but i am soooo stuck been messing with this for hours now.

On this link...
https://www.brandsurveycollection.com/treatedSurvey.htm

Their is a horizontal scroll bar at the bottom and i cant figure out why. The only thing that i found is if i remove the sections for Question 1 through 6 they go away. But i do Question 2 -6 then they remain or 1-5.

It is driving me crazy can anyone see what i might be missing here?

Comment: Please post the minimum code necessary to reproduce this issue in the question.

Comment: It's likely one or more of 42 HTML validation errors:  http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.brandsurveycollection.com%2FtreatedSurvey.htm&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: @Sparky nice catch.  ya, I shouldn't encourage that with css rules that cover up bad code...

Comment: In addition to posting the minimum amount of code within the OP itself, remove the annoying audio from your demo page... nobody here wants to be blasted.

Comment: Learning how to use your browser's DOM inspection tools would have saved hours of wasted time.

Comment: You should also fix the other [42 errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.brandsurveycollection.com%2FtreatedSurvey.htm&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

Comment: +1 above, I like using Firefox's 3D view for dealing with pesky width issues. Its helps visualize and looks cool if someone happens to be walking by...https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/3D_view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the `width` of the `labels`:

```css
 .question-wrap .input-wrap ul li label {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 640px;  /* remove  */
}
```

Remove the `width` and the `scrollbar`will be gone.

Comment: Thanks Vucko ur exactly right

Answer (score 0):

Try removing or setting the CSS width to auto for your radio and check mark buttons.

```
.question-wrap .input-wrap ul li label {
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike! I got it now